# Is there any way to recover my application in ruby on rails if I have a copy at the git repository?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have stupidly named a new web_app the same name in my ruby on rails directory.

And now I tried to look back the "blog" in the browser, all is gone.

Now, I have a copy of the application in git repository.

Is there anyway I can pull it down to the command prompt in my computer?

Hope someone can advise me how to.

I have so far tried git pull origin master and the rails command prompts only said master -> Fetch Head

But, still nothing shows up in the browser when I type localhost:3000 etc..

Thanks.

Comment: Did you also answer "Yes" to all those "Should I overwrite this file?" without realizing that you're overwriting an existing app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]You should be able to clone it.
Run the git clone command.

`git clone` (the url to your remote repository)

If you go to your repository on the right hand side of the page you will find the url to clone.

Comment: I did what it did. And it says fatal: destination path 'blog' already exists...Anyway, I started the rails server again, and my blog shows up in the browser now. Thanks for your help.  Learnt something new today. :)